# What's up with the unofficial SO meta-discussion board?

Tags: discussion, external-project

I was led to [this site](http://sof.modos.org/forum/) ([via](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/cmon-get-meta/)) and am wondering why it is still alive.

Comment: Last post in 2009; I wouldn't call that "alive" :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was my attempt at a meta-discussion site before Meta existed. I've now taken it offline.